# Basic CSS Help - Removing a shape

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, shapes

I'm trying to disable the triangles above the element labels via css. To view these, press a link, (hear, see, savor) There is dotted line and text. On the text there is a little red triangle/arrow that is not centered.I have done it successfully for the menus, but not the element labels. The website in question is: tedmartinez.com

```
.content-title span:before {
display: none;
}

.content-title span:before {

     content: none;

}

span.content-title {
    display:none;
}
span {
    display:none;
}

.content-title span:before {
    content: none;
}
#content-title span:before {
    content: none;
}
```

This code above does not work for disabling it on the element/content titles.

```
/*removing all arrows and triangles from Tripod*/
nav.main-menu > ul > li.selected:before, nav.main-menu > ul > li.active:before {
content: none;
}

nav.main-menu>ul>li:last-child:after{
content: none;
}

.sf-menu > li:hover > ul:before,
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > ul:before {
content: none;
}

nav.main-menu > ul > li:before {
    content: none;
}

.widget h5.widget-title span:before {
    content: none;
}

#reply-title span:before, #comments-title span:before, .related-title span:before {
    content: none;
}
/*tripod menu arrows while active*/
    nav.main-menu > ul > li.selected:before, nav.main-menu > ul > li.active:before {
            content: none;}

/*tripod menu arrows while hover*/
    nav.main-menu > ul.sf-menu li:hover:before, nav.main-menu > ul.sf-menu li.sfHover:before{
            content: none;}
```

This worked for disabling it on the menu.

That doesn't work. When I edit the HTML, just under inspect element in my browser, if I delete the span tags it works. Also, I want to center the text for the element labels. Go to the savor page to see. I want the savor to be on one line, and then a moment to be on the other, while remaining center. How can I do so? Thank you so much!

Comment: You didn't post your link

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith    It's posted there, tedmartinez.com. I don't know why it didn't turn into a hyperlink. Maybe I did that wrong :(

Comment: @Yomo710 use Markup for links: `[link](http://example.com)`

Comment: @Bastiaan Sure, [Tedmartinez.com](http://tedmartinez.com) I was under the assumption that it would link automatically.

Comment: @Yomo710 it doesn't link automatically because you didn't include "http://". Without that it doesn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.content-title span:before{
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

To answer your second question set width to 50% to keep your text from wrapping

```
 .content-title span {
  padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I set the class to it and it worked like a charm. For all those that are wondering, in the future, if you ever encounter this problem this is what i used.

Comment: .content-title span:before{
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can solve the other problem? I want to center the text for the element labels. Go to the savor page to see. I want the savor to be on one line, and then a moment to be on the other, while remaining center. How can I do so? Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, view my update, let me know if that works for ya

Comment: I added &nbsp; tags so that it would be aligned better. For some odd reason, the padding was messed up without them.

Comment: its because its a label, labels do do not have text-align atributes which makes aligning them next too impossible

Comment: Oh okay. Quick question, when you edited the CSS, what tool did you use? I want to get it too. Is it firebug?